# Template Driven Form Validation of component inside Form

Tags: angular

I am trying to validate a component inside a form

```
  <form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <app-form-component [f]="f" [model]="model" ></app-form-component>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Form component:

```
         <input type="number"
                   #test="ngModel"
                   name="test"
                   required
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && test.invalid }"
                   [(ngModel)]="model">
```

When I submit the form I get an error in my Input Filed but the function submitForm is still called.

Comment: As per your question your validation fire but sumitForm is called is your main problem?

Comment: yes. The form submits although its invalid

Comment: So you need to disabled the submit button using model invalid right?

Comment: No. Then the input Error would not occur.

Comment: Ok. I got your point so you need to write ternary operator in (ngSubmit)="submitForm()"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="CheckModelValid()?submitForm():''">
```

Component File Add One function Which Return Model Is Valid Or not that call

```
CheckModelValid(){
 ..... 
 return true // on valid
}
```

you can also check the validation with below ways:

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submitForm()">
```

if form is valid then only submitForm function call.

Comment: That's not quite was I was looking for. Seems more like a workaround. And I would still need to get the Validation Information from the component.